# Compiling NekoVM dll on win32

Tags: compilation, haxe, neko

Neko is a virtual machine for the Haxe languge. I am having some problem with compiling it on win32. The version in question is neko-1.8.1.tar.gz, which can be downloaded from http://nekovm.org/download.

There is a project file `\neko-1.8.1\vm\nekovm_dll.vcproj`  which references `gc.lib`:

> `AdditionalDependencies="../libs/include/gc/gc.lib"`

Also, some files, like `alloc.c` tries to `#include "gc/gc.h"`. Both `gc.lib` and `gc.h` are missing from the source package. So, where are these files?

**Thanks for your help!**

*(Please don't tell me that there are precompiled binaries. I don't need them.)*

Answer (score 0):

Those files are the references to the garbage collector, which by now is Boehm GC. You can download it from [this link](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). From there you most probably will need to compile it on windows to get gc.dll and gc.lib .